# Looking at someone with an intent

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Imagine in a party you notice a man is looking at your friend's ex-girlfriend in a manner that sounds she has some sexual attractions for him and you want to show that guy's look when he has focused on that girl to your friend (who is your and the girls last boyfriend's mutual friend.) I would appreciate it if someone could let me know which one of the following sentences work properly here:

> - Look at him. He is **looking at** Maria **intentfully**.
> - Look at him. He **has an intent look on** Maria.

If they both do not work here, then please let me know how a native speaker would say the same thing. (I think the message in my question is clear.)

Comment: The first one works, the adverb intentfully (full of intent) would be correct.

Comment: The use of "intent" doesn't really fit here. An intent is simply an inner purpose behind an action. "I'm sorry I hurt you; that wasn't my _intent_" What is his intent? To harm? To seduce? To create a state of curiosity? Also, don't get it confused with "intensely," which simply means strongly or forcefully.

Comment: To look at someone ***intently***. NOT; with fully.

Comment: Intent, intention are two different words. intentfully does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use the word *intent* or *intentfully* to indicate sexual attraction. Instead, I'd suggest the relatively informal phrasal verb *check out*:

> Look at him. He's checking out Maria.

You could also use the verb *eyeing*:

> Look at him. He's eyeing Maria.

Most dictionaries I checked didn't provide definitions that would indicate these phrases are especially suitable. However, it's worth pointing out that the Urban Dictionary's top definition for *eyeing* is:

> *To check out a guy/girl. Someone you have a crush on or want to be with for whatever reason.*

Comment: Note: The Urban Dictionary is not necessarily a reliable source, but it does occasionally do a better job of capturing contemporary slang nuances than other, more traditional online dictionaries.